# Ignore blank text boxes before insertion into SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm working on a system that has a foreach loop that inserts a group of text boxes into a database. This code will loop for every car_init text box that exists on the previous page.

```
    foreach($_POST['car_init'] as $key => $car_init)
    {
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO CustBill_cars (C_ID, car_init, car_num, bolNum, bill_ID)
             SELECT $customer, UPPER('".$car_init."'), '".$car_num[$key]."', $pbolNum, MAX(CustBill_billing.bill_ID)
             FROM CustBill_billing";
    }
```

My question is: how do I ignore it if a text box is blank? Example: Someone enters in that they need 5 text boxes, but they actual only need 4. The 4 text boxes are filled and the 5th one is blank, how do I just insert the 4 text boxes with information and ignore the blank one.

EDIT: I fixed the problem. I needed to add

```
    if(empty($car_init['car_init'])) { continue; }
```

before my insert statement.

Comment: Do your text boxes happen to be HTML checkboxes?

Comment: They are not. They are just text fields.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` condition:

```
foreach($_POST['car_init'] as $key => $car_init)
{
    if ($car_init) {
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO CustBill_cars (C_ID, car_init, car_num, bolNum, bill_ID)
             SELECT $customer, UPPER('".$car_init."'), '".$car_num[$key]."', $pbolNum, MAX(CustBill_billing.bill_ID)
             FROM CustBill_billing";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this, it still adds the blank text box, but adds the previous text boxes information instead. So if I have 3 car_init's, and insert "A" and "B" into text boxes 1 and 2, the 3rd text box will be "B."

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps you !!

```
  foreach($_POST['car_init'] as $key => $car_init)
     {

      $car_init = trim($car_init);
       if($car_init !=""){

             // add your insertion part here
         }

       }
```